# Codeigniter Cart: Adding an item to cart more than once replaces

Tags: codeigniter, shopping-cart

Using CI 2.1.1 and the native Cart library

If I insert an item (with same product id, same options) more than once, it replaces instead of increasing the qty.

Could this be a bug, am I missing something, or what would be the best way to add this functionality myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this was my solution, a change to System/libraries/Cart.php on line no. 233 to 244

There may be better ways to do this but it does the trick. I don't understand why the functionality isn't there already

```
    // EDIT:    added check if idential rowid/item already in cart, then just increase qty
    //          without this addition, it would not increase qty but simply replace the item
    if (array_key_exists($rowid, $this->_cart_contents)) 
    {  
       $this->_cart_contents[$rowid]['qty'] += $items['qty'];    
    } 
    else 
    {
        // let's unset this first, just to make sure our index contains only the data from this submission
        unset($this->_cart_contents[$rowid]);     

        // Create a new index with our new row ID
        $this->_cart_contents[$rowid]['rowid'] = $rowid;

        // And add the new items to the cart array
        foreach ($items as $key => $val)
        {
            $this->_cart_contents[$rowid][$key] = $val;
        }                       
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. Look at it this way: you're telling CI that you want 1 productX in your cart. If it's already there, it stays that way. The `rowid` does get updated.

Editing the core libraries is **not** a good idea. That makes your application depend on the changes you made and it can break it when you update CI and forget to change the core again.

If you really want to be able to increase the `qty` every time the user clicks on Add then
I would suggest is to do something similar to what you did, but in you `model`.
Check if the product is already in cart, get the `qty` and add existing `qty` to the new one.
Does this make sense?